# Exposing jndi variables as property place holder

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-batch

I have a jar containing a spring configuration. I am retrieving some JNDI variables to configure web service addresses inside the jar. Now, I am using the same jar in a Spring Batch and I would like to use the same spring configuration file.

My problem is that I am passing the web service addresses as system properties to my batch with the

```
java -DmyFoo=bar
```

Using this

```
<context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

I can get my variables as @Value("myFoo")

So my question is: is there any way to be able to get my JNDI variables in my property placeholder? Or be able to get them as JNDI and then expose them in a property placeholder?

What I want to be able to do is replace this

```
<bean id="MBean" class="com.xxx.utils.ActivationMBean">
    <property name="makeCall">
        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="semantic.activation" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

By this

```
<bean id="MBean" class="com.xxx.utils.ActivationMBean">
    <property name="makeCall" value="${semantic.activation}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Use a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` instead. And I strongly suggest using the namespace `<context:property-placeholder />` instead.

Comment: Ok I did this in my batch, but how can I get the JNDI as ${semantic.activation}?

Comment: Not sure if I understand but `semantic.activation` is resolved using (amongst others) the `JndiPropertySource`. So it is already being looked up, assuming you are using the `ProperySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer`. So basically your replacement should already work, without any additional effort. Make sure that you use the version-less `spring-context.xsd` or at least version 3.0 else you will still get a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`.

Comment: Well server side I have this:
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:properties/*.properties" />
What do I need to do so it also look up in the JNDI? I am using the version-less spring-context.xsd with spring 3.2.8.

Comment: As stated it will already do a lookup in JNDI by using the `JndiPropertySource`. It will do a lookup for `java:comp/env/semantic.activation`. If you want it to fail don't set `ignore-unresolvable-placeholders` and do't add the property to your properties file. Then it will fail.

Comment: Well, then for some reasons it is not working

Comment: Then there must be something you aren't telling or showing us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `<context:property-placeholder />` a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) is registered. (That is when you are on Spring 3.1 or later and are using the xsd without version or a version > 3.0). The [property-source abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-property-source-abstraction) has been added in Spring 3.1.

The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` uses the configured `PropertySource`s to obtain values for placeholders. The `PropertySource`s consulted depends on the environment, web or non-web, and the amount of `@PropertySource` annotations or loaded property files through the `location` attribute of the `<context:property-placeholder />` elements.

For the [`StandardServletEnvironment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment.html) (web) the `PropertySource`s are consulted in the following order.

1. ServletContext init-params
2. ServletContext context-params
3. JndiPropertySource
4. System Properties
5. System Environment

For the [`StandardEnvironment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment.html) (non-web) the `PropertySource`s are consulted in the following order.

1. System Properties
2. System Environment

Depending on the setting of the `localOverride` property properties loaded from properties files are added to the top (`true`) or to the bottom  (`false`) of the list of `PropertySource`s to consult.

Given the following bean definition.

```
<bean id="MBean" class="com.xxx.utils.ActivationMBean">
    <property name="makeCall" value="${semantic.activation}" />
</bean>
```

In a web environment the placeholder `${semantic.activation}` is being [resolved](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#_placeholder_resolution_in_statements) first against the JNDI tree if that isn't found it will fallback to the System Properties. For a non-web no JNDI lookup is attempted and properties specified by `-D` or in the environment are consulted.

Comment: Thank you for your determination to help me solve this problem!
The thing I was missing is that I was using 2 files and did not put the "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd" in the second file. Adding this solve my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a trick that makes what I need:

```
<bean id="MBean" class="com.xxx.utils.ActivationMBean">
    <property name="makeCall">
        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="semantic.activation" default-value="${semantic.activation}" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

It can't be used with the @Value annotation but if we are using JNDI it will take it and not it will fall back to the property. If none is defined it will fail to start and that is what I wanted.

Comment: Which is also what the `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` does by consulting the `JndiPropertySource`. You are making it way to complex. As I tried to explain this is default behavior since the introduction of `PropertySource`s.

Comment: Yes the <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="semantic.activation"/> will look up the java:comp/env/semantic.activation variable. But how can I use it in my batch where I do not have a JNDI service? That's why I need to have the default value that will be filled with the java -Dsemantic.activation system property.