# Spring jndi.xml placement holder using environment variable

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a tomcat application with jndi.xml file that has placeholder. This file contains placeholder `${...}` and I want it to be replaced from environment variable.

jndi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <bean id="widgetsRestBaseUrl" class="java.lang.String" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg value="${widgetsRestBaseUrl}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

From my understanding, `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` resolves `${...}` in bean definition , so I expected it to work, but it doesn't. Am I missing anything from here? I do see `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` class in my project from spring. And I also do set environment variable, checked using `printenv`.

EDIT: I found that I need to have some `<context:property-placeholder />`, but not sure what it means.
[Exposing jndi variables as property place holder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140673/exposing-jndi-variables-as-property-place-holder)

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found that adding `<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true"/>` in my context.xml file did the trick. From [Exposing jndi variables as property place holder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140673/exposing-jndi-variables-as-property-place-holder)